# Projection in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to move my `Sprite` in `AndEngine` in a projectile motion.

Can any one help me in this matter with a piece of code? Unfortunately I didn't see an example about projections in `AndEngine`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the UpdateModifier, I suspect.

How do you want your Sprite to move?  Do you want it to find a path to the destination or are you just trying to keep something on the screen?  Are you using a Camera?  All of that will determine how exactly you should approach getting your Sprite to move.

This is a link for the tut about UpdateModifiers:

[Update Handlers - Using their Power!](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/update-handlers-using-their-power-t475.html%22)

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: yeah i know about update manager...all I was looking for is a code for projection in andEngine. I was looking for built in functionality but I didnt find any. So I build a custom function which takes velocity and angle and move the sprite at that angle with that velocity.

Answer (score 2):

for a projectile move , you can use the physicshandler and then you can manipulate the acceleration and velocity to make it move like projectile...

```
projectile=new Sprite(X,Y, ProjectileTextureRegion);
physprojectile = new PhysicsHandler(projectile);
projectile.registerUpdateHandler(physprojectile);
physprojectile.setVelocityX(Xvelocity);
physprojectile.setVelocityY(Yvelocity);
pyhsprojectile.setAcceleration(Accelration)  //negative acceleration
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use registerEntityMofidier on a sprite (or on any Entity): [Andengine EntityModifierExample](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/EntityModifierExample.java)

Example:

```
sprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(TIME_IN_SECOND, fromX, toX, fromY, toY));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stakesprite.registerEntityModifier(new RotationModifier(0.1f, 0.0f,(float) ((360.0f/Math.PI)*Math.atan(velY/velX))));
            stake=PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, stakesprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            //stake = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, stakesprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
            stake.setBullet(true);
            stake.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(velX, velY));
            stake.setSleepingAllowed(true);
            mScene.attachChild(stakesprite);
```